# Как сортировать результаты из БД по полю, которое добавляется только в функции afterFind?

Tags: yii2

Приветствую. Есть, к примеру, таблица товаров с разными полями, функцией afterFind в модели добавляю пару кастомных полей:

```
public function afterFind() {
        $this->field= '...';
        $this->field2 = '....';
}
```

Но потом в контроллере надо сделать выборку из БД и сортировку именно по одному из кастомных полей:

```
$query = DB::find()->orderBy('field')->all();
```

В итоге имею ошибку, что column not found, что логично. Но как же заставить его сортировать по полю, которое добавляется через afterFind?

Comment: Функция **afterFind()** предназначена для работы с уже полученной моделью, а не для добавления кастомных полей. Вы определили поля **field** и **field2** в классе модели? Можете подробнее описать задачу?

Comment: orderBy('field') генерирует запрос в БД, в которой, естественно, данного поля нету. Сортируйте после выборки с помощью ArrayHelper::multisort